# Different Add to Cart button links for different products in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

How do I customize this php snippet to have different Add to Cart button links for different products throughout the website?

The code is intended to do the following

I.E:

Product with ID: 01 uses a Buy Button that redirects to www.example/ONE

Product with ID: 02 uses a Buy Button that redirects to www.example/TWO

Code I want to customize:

```
<?php   

function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() 
{ 
    return 'https://portal.veinternational.org/buybuttons/us051912/btn/test-001/'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );

?>
```

So, how would I take into account the product var ID in other to have different buy buttons links depending on the product ID?

Comment: I have delete my answer, as you are trying to make redirections to an external web site from add-to-cart button… You could not do that from `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` filter hook…